# What are these weird games in my steam library?

Tags: steam

I was cleaning out my steam library today and noticed something weird.

[image]

Dozens of games of the format, SteamAppXXXX, which don't seem to do anything. Given their... questionable nature, I haven't tried to install or run them.

What's going on here?

Comment: It seems like they're a residue from previous Steam apps of which the name has changed. Do they persist when you restart Steam? 1252 is to do with the game 'Killing Floor', is that one of the titles you removed? are you enrolled on any of the Steam betas?

Comment: Seems to me like Steam failed to get the app information for some reason.

Comment: @TZHX I *own* Killing Floor, but I don't think I've ever installed it on this computer. Not enrolled in any betas.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of the question? The answer to that question probably isn't relatable to this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug as stated here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/1q2cmh/suddenly_50_apps_in_my_library_all_named/cd8i0jg

Image for when the link is outdated:

[image]

I've read people are getting this while entering a game key. For some people restarting steam is fixing it.

Also a quote from the steam forums:

> Mine got fixed sometime in the past day. I got a message from Steam
>   Support about the ticket I filed and they gave me some steps to fix it
>   if their fix didn't take. I'll post them here so if someone is poking
>   around online they'll be able to find them:
>
> If the listings still apear, you may need to complete the steps below
>   to refresh your configuration files for Steam:
>
> Exit Steam.
>
> Please open Internet Explorer, Safari or Firefox and type
>   steam://flushconfig then press Enter. (If asked to allow this website
>   to open a program, please click 'Allow' or 'OK')
>
> When prompted by Steam to reset your configuration, please click 'OK'
>   to confirm.
>
> Once done, login to Steam and re-test the issue.
>
> If you have multiple installation folders for games doing this process
>   will remove them. You will need to add the folders again in Steam so
>   that your games will appear as installed.
>
> In order to add the folders please do the following:
>
> 1. Open Steam
> 2. Click Steam > Settings (Preferences on Mac)
> 3. Navigate to the 'Downloads' tab
> 4. Click the 'Steam Library Folders' button
> 5. Click on 'Add Library Folder' and add the directory that contains your games
> 6. Click 'OK'
> 7. Restart Steam
>
> So there you go. Happy gaming.

Source: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/666825524823897362/#p14

I dont think it's clear what the bug really is. The `1252` etc behind it are probably the AppId's